# SQL query works in EA but doesn't work with C# on the API

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I created a C# script that builds a sql query with data from an excel and then queries the EA repository.

```
sqlquery_part1A = "select obj.object_id from (t_object obj inner join t_connector j on (obj.Object_ID=j.end_Object_ID)) inner join t_object endobj on (j.start_Object_ID=endobj.Object_ID) where obj.alias = '" + adu_alias.Replace("'", "''") + "' and endobj.Name = '" + datastream + "' and obj.Name = '" + adu_name + "'";
int element_count = repository.GetElementSet(sqlquery_part1A, 2).Count;
```

The query works fine, except when one of the fields coming from excel has break lines. E.g.

```
"global_sla_l2p_nrt.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SLA NRT), 

global_swh_l2p_nrt.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SWH NRT), 

global_sla_l2p_stc.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SLA STC)"
```

When this happens the script finds no entries in the repository. However, if I take the exact same query to EA it returns an entry.

Here is an example of a query:

```
select obj.object_id from (t_object obj inner join t_connector j on (obj.Object_ID=j.end_Object_ID)) inner join t_object endobj on (j.start_Object_ID=endobj.Object_ID) where obj.alias = 'global_sla_l2p_nrt.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SLA NRT), 

global_swh_l2p_nrt.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SWH NRT), 

global_sla_l2p_stc.*\.nc(|\.gz)$ (Product: L2P-SLA STC)' and endobj.Name = 'DIS-ING.FTP' and obj.Name = 'L2P  Service products'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post an example of the actual query?

Comment: Line breaks are always tricky. Theres \n, \r, \n\r and \r\n. I always go through the permutations. Alternatively use a LIKE and replace them with a wildcard.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I've added an example in que question.

Comment: Hum, I think I may have solved it by adding: 
sqlquery_part1A = sqlquery_part1A.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);

Comment: You should be using proper parameterization, then you won;t have such problems. What would you do if one of the values had `'; DROP DATABASE MyDb; --`

Comment: @Charlieface not in this case. EA's api asks for a string with the select statement.

Comment: @GeertBellekens OP has *"a C# script that builds a sql query with data from an excel"* that script itself should be using parameterization in some way. If that needs to go all the way back to the Excel sheet in order that the user can separate the query from input data, then so be it. Data <> query, and should never be mixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to replace the break line with Environment.NewLine:

```
sqlquery_part1A = sqlquery_part1A.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer...